# Wordpress action - Pass arguments into action in an AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, actions

My theme uses a custom action which expects two arguments. I am trying to call the function in an AJAX call but because I am not passing those arguments I end up getting a 500 error.

The action is formatted like this:

```
function newsletterSignup($id, $source) {
   // code here
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_newsletter_signup', 'newsletterSignup');
add_action('wp_ajax_newsletter_signup', 'newsletterSignup');
```

My ajax call looks like this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this),
        fd = new FormData($form[0]);

    fd.append('action','newsletter_signup');
    fd.append('source','homepage');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: user_object.ajaxurl,
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // registered
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            //error
        }
    });
});
```

As mentioned, I am getting a 500 error on this request because the action does not include the `$id` and `$source` arguments. Is it possible to pass arguments into the action via JavaScript?

Comment: a 500 error is a generic something went wrong message from the server, it's not the actual error. You need to look in your PHP error log to find the error message. Also, is there a reason you used the old legacy AJAX API instead of the modern REST API for your AJAX requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass arguments to `wp_ajax_` callbacks. You need to pass the data via the `data` property of the AJAX request. Then you get those values with `$_POST` and pass them to a function:

```
function newsletterSignupAjax() {
   $id     = $_POST['id'];
   $source = $_POST['source'];

    /* Make sure to validate and sanitize those values. */

    newsletterSignup( $id, $source );
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_newsletter_signup', 'newsletterSignupAjax');
add_action('wp_ajax_newsletter_signup', 'newsletterSignupAjax');
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you